# building a pro in qtcreator gives "qtWidgets: No such file or directory"

Tags: qt-creator

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. After installing qtcreator 3.5.1, opening and building a .pro file gives the following error:

```
qtWidgets: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the default qt build Kit has been set to qt 4.x rather than qt 5.x when qtcreator was installed. To update this;

qtcreator - options - build & run - Kits - Manual - Desktop (default) - Qt version

Change Qt version from qt 4.x.. to qt 5.x.. in PATH (qt5).